# Detox/Jest Test suite failed to run TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, detox

I'm trying to integrate some e2e tests into my react native (expo ejected) mobile project. I'm following the instructions found on the detox [Getting Started](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/getting-started) page. I'm able to successfully build my project, but everytime I attempt the detox test command:

```
detox test --configuration ios --loglevel trace
```

I get the following error:

```
FAIL  e2e/firstTest.e2e.jsrun...
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest-circus/environment.js:24:38)
      at Object.newLoader (../node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest-circus/index.js:4:32)

09:07:59.324 detox[21032] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:android:).)*$' e2e
```

I have a fairly simple out-of-the-box configuration of detox and jest:

**package.json**

```
...
"detox": "^19.6.2"
"jest": "^27.0.0",
"jest-circus": "^27.5.1",
...
```

**./e2e/config.json**

```
{
  "testEnvironment": "./environment",
  "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
  "testTimeout": 120000,
  "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.js$",
  "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
  "verbose": true
}
```

**./e2e/environment.js**

```
const {
  DetoxCircusEnvironment,
  SpecReporter,
  WorkerAssignReporter,
} = require('detox/runners/jest-circus');

class CustomDetoxEnvironment extends DetoxCircusEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);

    // Can be safely removed, if you are content with the default value (=300000ms)
    this.initTimeout = 300000;

    // This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, Jest only reports at file-level.
    // This is strictly optional.
    this.registerListeners({
      SpecReporter,
      WorkerAssignReporter,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = CustomDetoxEnvironment;
```

**.detoxrc.json**

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
  "apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Example.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/Example.xcworkspace -configuration release -scheme Example -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    },
    "android": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "SPECIFY_PATH_TO_YOUR_APP_BINARY"
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 12 Pro"
      }
    },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android"
    }
  }
}
```

It can't be this hard.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to solve using Jest 27.0.1

[I asked on github because I had the same problem as you and they gave me this solution](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3378)